# Command to set user and password for 802.1X PEAP authentication in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, exe, lan

hello you lovely people,

I am trying to rollout the 802.1X PEAP authentication on a group of HP Thin Clients with Win7 Embedded and XP embedded,
without setting up each one individually by hand.

The point where I get stuck is the user and password. (see picture)
[PEAP login mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJves.png)
I am loocking for a command or so for a batch or powershell with which I can enter the data.
or maybe there is another solution that I do not know yet.

This is the code i already have:

```
@echo off
echo .
echo .
cls

IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)

:: starts the service to enable 802.1X
:32BIT
sc start dot3svc
sc config dot3svc start= auto

goto 86BIT

:: install the certificate only on 64 bit TCs
:64BIT
certutil -f -addstore "Root" "C:\Temp\myrootCA.p7b"

goto 86BIT

:: overwrites the network profile with the wanted settings
:86BIT
netsh lan add profile filename=C:\Temp\LAN.xml interface=*
netsh lan reconnect interface=*

:: fill me with the missing code <3

pause

exit
```

I am looking forward to your comments.

With kind regards

I